The soft hey of Bemidbar 15:31
Seems it wants to assume the possessive dagesh in the hey. What do we do with this form grammatically? Ty All!

This sort of thing happens in a few other places, like vayikra 13:4 or bamidbar 32:42

Is Vayikra 12:4 an example of this?

For a historical linguistics answer, the form used to be vowel+ha, like laha. That got simplified in two ways: dropping the final vowel (לָהּ) or dropping the h (לָהֿ). If that kind of answer satisfies, I can try to write it up below.
